# PHP what is the easiest way to create users?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to create a very simple website with just 10 users for my school project. I am trying to use simplest code as possible. So I figured it would be best to hard code username/password combinations to a php file.

Like,

```
$users = array ('Shannon'=>array('password1')
```

I just want to create 10 variables that contains passwords. So I figured an array would be best option.

Can anybody explain to me how to create a two dimensional array then later on retrieve the array information to authenticate logging in ?

PS I have a good background in C++.

Comment: What you have tried yet ??

Comment: The simplest code is not necessarily the best code. I think you would agree that saving plain hardcoded passwords into a file is a terrible idea. I guess your other 9 users would agree. (If you're using >= PHP5.5 - http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.password.php)

Comment: Is this one line of code everything you have?

Comment: Create an array with length=10, then store user array in each "slot". $array = array(array("username"=>"user1","password"=>"password1"), array("username"=>"user2","password"=>"password2")...);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple as hell.

```
$users = array();
$users['Shannon'] = array('Password' => 'Banana');
$users['April'] = array('Password' => 'Qwerty');

$name = 'April'; // Entered in login form name
$password = 'Apple'; // Entered in login form password

if($users[$name]['password'] == $password) {
    // login
} else {
    // dont login
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I know this supposed to be simple, I just don't know how to use syntax, this will help me a lot as how to use php syntax getting clearer to me. Thannk you very much!

Answer (score 1):

```
$users = array('user1'=> array('username' => 'Shannon, 'password' => herPassword'),   
'user2' => array('username' => 'Shannon, 'password' => herPassword'))



foreach($users as $user) {
    if ($user['username'] == 'USERINPUT' AND $user['password'] == 'USERINPUTPASSWORD) { 
    // log the user in
    }
}
```

This would be the solution, for a PRIVATE website only! Normally you are working with a database, where you store each account in. Then you would escape the user input aswell, to make sure that nobody stores invalid things into your database, and to prevent your database from SQL Injection.

Answer (score 0):

If you want filling details manually you can do something like.

```
$users=array();
$user['Shannon']="password";
$user['user2']="password2";
and so on
```

and check for password like

```
$username=$_POST['username'];
if(isset($user[$username])&&$user[$username]===$_POST['password'])
//Login sucessfull
```

**Note:** This is very bad idea for doing registration like this and storing passwords in plain text.

Comment: Thank you!! To this website the security is not important. I only need to make it look like a professional website and present it to the class. The site will come down in two weeks after I get the grade. I know this is very basic and it might not be exiting for you to answer,thank you for taking your time